# Bar chart showing count of each category month-wise using Bokeh

Tags: python, bar-chart, bokeh

I have data as shown below:

[image: input data]

So, from this, I need to display the count in each category year_month_id wise. Since I have 12 months there will be 12 sub-divisions and under each count of 
ID within each class.
Something like the image below is what I am looking for.

[image]

Now the examples in Bokeh use ColumnDataSource and dictionary mapping, but how do I do this for my dataset.
Can someone please help me with this?
Below is the expected output in tabular and chart format.

[image]

Comment: what does `ID` column value signify here ? It would be great if you post an example here like what count should be displayed for one category for one year

Comment: You want a bar chart of 'class' along the x-ax is and some quantity along the y-axis?  I don't see 'count' listed in your data.  You have it somewhere else?

Comment: Hello @BenLove,
Added the expected output for reference.Count will be the Count of ID within each class under each year_month_id.

Comment: Can you provide an actual CSV text of data? An image of a table is not useful for constructing a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) Python package would come in handy for preparing your data for plotting.  It's useful for manipulating table-like data structures.

Here is how I went about your problem:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis5

# Your sample data
df = DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1],
                'year_month_id': [201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201612, 201701],
                'class': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'other', 'other', 'other', 'A', 'other', 'A', 'B']
                })

# Get counts of groups of 'class' and fill in 'year_month_id' column
df2 = DataFrame({'count': df.groupby(["year_month_id", "class"]).size()}).reset_index()
```

df2 now looks like this:

[image]

```
# Create new column to make plotting easier
df2['class-date'] = df2['class'] + "-" + df2['year_month_id'].map(str)

# x and y axes
class_date = df2['class-date'].tolist()
count = df2['count'].tolist()

# Bokeh's mapping of column names and data lists
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(class_date=class_date, count=count, color=Viridis5))

# Bokeh's convenience function for creating a Figure object
p = figure(x_range=class_date, y_range=(0, 5), plot_height=350, title="Counts",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

# Render and show the vbar plot
p.vbar(x='class_date', top='count', width=0.9, color='color', source=source)
show(p)
```

So the Bokeh plot looks like this:

[image]

Of course you can alter it to suit your needs.  The first thing I thought of was making the top of the y_range variable so it could accommodate data better, though I have not tried it myself.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Can't thank you enough. @BenLove